# J2ME ProgressBar

Tags: java, user-interface, java-me

I want to make progressbar as seen in Gmail J2ME app

what should be done to make this??

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [`Gauge`](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Gauge.html) ? , [here](http://www.javabeat.net/articles/45-j2me-user-interface-2.html) is an example of it

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen the Gmail J2ME app, but I bet it doesn't use a `Gauge`.  J2ME apps usually used canvas-based UIs rather than form-based, because they're prettier.  A progress bar can be drawn using images (if you have a full progress bar image, you can paint as much of it as you need by using the [`Graphics.setClip()`](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Graphics.html) function).  Or you can use graphics primitives.

Answer (score 1):

To combine the previous two answers,  you could use the J2ME Polish library. This allows you to code as if you were using MIDP elements (such as Gauge), but allows you to customise how it looks.

http://www.j2mepolish.org/